# Difference between jsonstring and json object

Tags: string, json, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Can anyone tell me the difference between JSON string and JSON object?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation

Answer (score 1):

A Json Object is an object as parsed from a server. You then need to evaluate the Object to convert it into a String which you can then manipulate to retrieve the requited information.

Comment: Thanks Dev and Kevin.Here is the sample Jsons <br/>`{"id":1,"method":"myMessage","params":["{\"user\":\"Test\",\"message\":\"This is Cool\"}"]}`